# Entity Framework Core - Owned Entities don't aggregate using Linq

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm porting an EF project to EF Core.  The `[ComplexType]` attribute has been dropped and now we're using Owned Entities to accomplish the same function of embedding POCOs in Entities.  However, now all my Linq queries that involve groping have stopped working in that they no longer include the Owned values.

```
public class Order
{
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int SecurityId { get; set; }
    public Audit Audit { get; set; }
}

public class Audit
{
    public int CreatedUserId { get; set; }
    public Datetime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

if I execute

```
var firstOrder = (from o in orders
                 group o by o.OrderId
                 select o).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then my resulting set will have 'null' for all the 'Audit' properties.  In a way, it makes sense, but I'd still like an option to work around it.  Any ideas how to get the same functionality that you would get by aggregating the ComplexType in old EF?

Comment: The sample query does not compile. But I was able to reproduce the issue. Apparently EF Core bug, consider reporting it (with correct example) to their issue tracker. The workaround is to use `from o in db.Orders.Include(x => x.Audit)`, which is weird because owned types are supposed to be [always loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#querying-owned-types).

Comment: That didn't work, but it was close.  I had to add the 'Include' method to the final IQueryable (after the grouping is done).  That is, the solution that worked for me is ((from o in orders group o by o.OrderId o).FirstOrDefault()).Include(o => o.Audit);